# I have a code running in a GCP cluster and I am trying to connect it to the spark UI but it says it cannot connect to port 8080?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-ui

bind [::1]:8080: Cannot assign requested address
Linux data-eng-m 5.10.0-0.deb10.16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-2~bpo10+1 (2022-07-28) x86_64

This is the error that I keep getting. I created my application in my notebook running in the cluster but when I run my code in the console it says that it cannot connect to port 8080. I tried seeing if other things were running on it but there is nothing else.

This is how I started my connection to spark in my notebook:

```py
app_name = "week1_demo"
master = "local[*]"
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName(app_name)\
    .master(master)\
    .config("spark.ui.port","4229")\
    .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

This is what I ran in the console to select web preview on port 8080

```bash
ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list --filter="name~data-eng" --format "value(zone)")
gcloud compute ssh data-eng-m --ssh-flag "-L 8080:localhost:42229" --zone $ZONE
```

How can I get my port to work or how can I connect to a different port?

I tried a new cluster to completely restart the cluster but still the same error

Comment: I would suggest to contacting Google Support for this as they have better visbility of your project's logs and resource use and possibly help you with your network concern. https://cloud.google.com/contact